# adjustwidth in a newenvironment

Tags: environments, adjustwidth

What is the right syntax for the \newenvironment command in this example to get myadjustwidth work as adjustwidth does?

```
\documentclass[10pt,twoside,toc=listofnumbered,headinclude,footinclude,index=numbered]{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{changepage}

\newenvironment{myadjustwidth}
{\begin{adjustwidth}{3.5mm}{0cm}%
\end{adjustwidth}}

\begin{document}

\blindtext

\begin{adjustwidth}{3.5mm}{0cm}
\blindtext
\end{adjustwidth}

\begin{myadjustwidth}
\blindtext
\end{myadjustwidth}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You missed a closing and opening group braces. The correct syntax is `\newenvironment{<env name>}{<begin>}{<end>}`:

```
\documentclass[10pt,twoside,toc=listofnumbered,headinclude,footinclude,index=numbered]{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{changepage}

\newenvironment{myadjustwidth}% <name>
{\begin{adjustwidth}{3.5mm}{0cm}}% <begin> (note the additional closing brace) 
{\end{adjustwidth}}% <end> (note the additional opening brace)

\begin{document}

\blindtext

\begin{adjustwidth}{3.5mm}{0cm}
\blindtext
\end{adjustwidth}

\begin{myadjustwidth}
\blindtext
\end{myadjustwidth}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's it. Thx. Harald